# Twilio TwiML Say then Play in an incoming call

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

I need my app to be able to first say something to an incoming call and then play a recording in loop.

This piece of ruby code used to do what I wanted but it seems like it's not working anymore.

```
return 200, Twilio::TwiML::VoiceResponse.new do |r|
  r.say(voice: 'alice', message: 'Hello World')
  r.play(
    loop: 0,
    url: 'https://my-domain/beep'
  )
end.to_s
```

This code generates the following XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Say voice="Alice">Hello World</Say>
    <Play loop="0">https://my-domain/beep</Play>
</Response>
```

Alice says what she's supposed to say but the looping test beep is not played. I have verified that my server serves a proper `Content-Type: audio/x-wav` file for `beep`.

I'd appreciate any pointers on how to achieve what I'm trying to do.

Comment: What is the resulting TwiML created by the Ruby code above, that should immediately identify the issue.

Comment: @Alan I added the generated TwiML. Thank you.

Comment: Possibly the encoding of the media file is problematic? I have seen that before and then used a tool like Audacity to save it as a .mp3 or .wav (to get it re-encoded). Also, check the Twilio Call log. Look for the CallSID for this call and see if there are any errors when you click into the call and also view the Request Inspector output for that call.

Comment: @Alan it turns out the issue was caching. Twilio was caching the old beep (which was intentionally silent). Everything was working as intended.

Comment: Ahh nice, yea caching can be tricky. We have an article on it here, https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223180508-How-can-I-change-the-cache-behavior-of-audio-files-.

Answer (score 0):

### Respond to Incoming Phone Calls in `Ruby`

```
# Get twilio-ruby from twilio.com/docs/ruby/install
require 'sinatra'
require 'twilio-ruby'

post '/voice' do
  city = params['FromCity']

  # Start our TwiML response
  Twilio::TwiML::VoiceResponse.new do |r|
    # Use <Say> to give the caller some instructions
    r.say("Never gonna give you up #{city}.", voice: 'alice')
    r.play(url: 'https://demo.twilio.com/docs/classic.mp3')
  end.to_s
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I don't see what your code is doing different than mine. Care to elaborate?

Comment: This code is a Ruby language and you have to a play voice. I have not understood you have to do?

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, this was caused by Twilio caching the old wav file (which happened to be silent on purpose). Once the cache is refreshed, Twilio now plays the correct sound file.

I hope this helps somebody.